# How to transform an angular API into a synchronous one

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to make consecutive http calls to a REST service but **every call uses an unique valid token** in the call header, so if I have some components initializing at the same time they are making "get" calls at the same time with the same token so I need to modify my get function to make one call, wait for the response, **take the new token** from that response and use it in the next call and so on for the next calls.

My custom http service

```
    @Injectable()
    export class HttpCustomService {

    token: string;
    activeRequestsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
              private authService: AuthService) {

       this.authService.token$.subscribe(
       token => this.token = token
       );
    }

    getHeaders( withToken: boolean) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; 
    charset=UTF-8', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache' });
    if (withToken) {
        headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                  'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`, 
                  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache'} );
    }

    return headers;
  }

  get(url: string, withToken: boolean): Observable<any> {
      this.loadingSubject.next(true);
      const options = {
      headers: this.getHeaders(withToken)
    };
    this.incrementActiveRequest();
    return this.httpClient.request('get', url, options).do(
      response => {
        if (response.body && response.body.token) {
          this.authService.setToken(response.body.token);
        }
        this.loadingSubject.next(false);
        this.decrementActiveRequest();
      },
      error => {this.loadingSubject.next(false);
                this.decrementActiveRequest();
      });
  }
```

These are examples how I use that service

```
getQuotes(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpCustom.get(`${this.urlBase}/quotes`, true)
        .map((response: any) => {
            return response.body.result;
        }).catch(err => {
            this.handleError(err);
            return Observable.of(null);
        });
}

getPolicies(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpCustom.get(`${this.urlBase}/policies`, true)
        .map((response: any) => {
            return response.body.result;
        }).catch(err => {
            this.handleError(err);
            return Observable.of(null);
        });
}
```

I think I have to use flatMap but I don't know how to use it in my "get" method. Any ideas?

Comment: you cannot turn an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one. Are you asking how to wait for the result of one operation before proceeding to the next?

Comment: I'm not sure how practical what your after is, if you control the server, I would change your security scheme. A new token on every request doesn't add much in terms of security and is fairly impractical in modern web. Your apps performance will be very poor if you're unable to execute parallel requests.

Comment: Yes, I need that every time I make a "get" call I have to wait for its response to get a new token for the possible next calls. I know that it affects the performance but unfortunately I cannot change anything in the background server

Comment: Then you shouldn't be trying to make an SPA with that server behind it. You'll make progress and hten run into another issue, and hten another and then another.  Your server is outdated, and you're trying to make it work with something modern.

Comment: The only way you can do this is by setting up some kind of execution queue in your service and ensuring they get executed one by one that way.

Comment: I still think this is a bad idea but I'm kind of intrigued by the concept so if you set up a plunkr I'll put some work into it

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood, but think the change is small

> every call uses an unique valid token

so you don't want to this in the constructor,

```
constructor(private ...) {
  this.authService.token$.subscribe(token => this.token = token);
}
```

you want to do it first in every get,

```
get(url...) {
  this.authService.token$.map(token => {
    const headers = this.getHeaders(token);
    ...
    this.httpClient.request(...)
  });
}
```

Do you need to save the token in authService if it's single-shot?

Also, I think above `activeRequestsSubject` is the same variable as `loadingSubject`

**Edit**
Correcting after comment by OP - changed `this.authService.token$.subscribe` to `this.authService.token$.map`.

Comment: I tried previously with a similar approach with no success. The problem with that solution is that you are subscribed to an observable that will never return a new value becasue you're not making any call, so no new token will be generated. I found a solution adding some rxjs operators to the token subscription. I'm posting it..

Comment: Of course, you're right - should nest the calls with `map` not `subscribe`.

Answer (score 0):

I apparently found a solution. Thanks for all the comments, all of them have helped me in some way.

My new get method:

```
get(url: string): Observable<any> {
if (this.activeRequestsSubject.value === 0) {
  this.incrementActiveRequest();
  const headers = {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                                              'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`,
                                              'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                                              'Pragma': 'no-cache'})};
  return this.httpClient.request('get', url, headers)
                          .do(res => {
                            this.decrementActiveRequest();
                            this.authService.setToken(res['token']);
                            return res; });
}else {
  this.incrementActiveRequest();
  return this.authService.token$.skip(this.activeRequestsSubject.value - 2).first().mergeMap(
     (token: string) => {
      const headers = {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                                                  'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                                                  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                                                  'Pragma': 'no-cache'})};
      return this.httpClient.request('get', url, headers).do(res => {
                                                                    this.decrementActiveRequest();
                                                                    this.authService.setToken(res['token']);
                                                                    return res; });
      }
     );
}
```

}

Comment: this will work if your app is fairly simple but will run into issues and unpredictable behavior with many concurrent requests.

Comment: @bryan60 could you be more precise? I'm using it in an application where I have some components in a same page and all of them initializes at the same time within it's own ngOnInit with some "get" requests at the same time and it's working correctly so far

Comment: I can’t because you’ve introduced state that exists outside of your observable stream in the form of your request counter. This means that your request counter and your actual requests could get out of sync if many concurrent requests come in at once. If it starts happening it’ll be hard to spot